# How to debug React Native Project (developed using Visual Studio Code) in Android Device

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, react-native, remote-debugging

Can anyone help me with the steps of how to debug React Native application in Android mobile. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native has helped me to debug to an Emulator but it does not say anything on Android Devices. At one point they asked me to enable Debug JS Remotely but I couldn't find this feature in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your app is already running on a physical device follow steps from step 5

step 1. Enable Debugging over USB

step  2. Plug in your device via USB

step 3. Check that your device is properly connecting to ADB

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554 offline   # Google emulator
14ed2fcc device         # Physical device
```

Seeing device in the right column means the device is connected. You must have only one device connected at a time.

step 4. Run your app

```
react-native run-android
```

If you get a "bridge configuration isn't available" error, see [Using adb reverse.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#method-1-using-adb-reverse-recommended)

step 5. After the app is running on your device **Physically shake your device** to see options

step 6. Keep Chrome open

step 7. select  Debug JS Remotely from the options

Debugger will open on chrome

Comment: Thanks Rizwan, I was looking for "Physically shake your device" only